# Xamarin Form: How to enable event behind a transparent contentView for iOS

Tags: xamarin, view, touch, transparent

I have a view which have a transparent background with other contents. Behind it, I have other controls which need to be interact by touch. For android, there is no problem touch the control behind the transparent area. In iOS, I can't interact the control behind the transparent view.

Is it possible to do it on iOS applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing touch events to appropriate sibling UIViews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918686/passing-touch-events-to-appropriate-sibling-uiviews)